# application 'xxx' died in status SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN:[qiankun] Target container with xxx not existed while '#xxx' mounting

Tags: umijs

I have a Qiankun application with multiple nested layers (three layers). Opening the grandchild application for the second time results in an error   (application 'xxx' died in status SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN:[qiankun] Target container with xxx not existed while '#xxx' mounting)

I found that the second time I opened the grandchild application, it triggered the 'unmount' lifecycle of the grandchild application. Why is this happening?